# DataTables nested table with collapse : how remove padding?

Tags: html, css, ajax, datatables, datatables-1.10

I created a demo to play with Datatables to have child row with Collapse/Expands. I'm not able to align the nested table within the parent.  I'll  like to have the same columns width.

You can see the JSFiddle here   [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/survivant/b0w2hhqp/8/)

I try to add this but it didn't work.

```
.childtable.dataTable tbody th, .childtable.dataTable tbody td {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: It is a real challenge since you are using a dataTable inside a dataTable, and the inline dataTable is a clone of another hidden <table>. There is so many aspects where any attempt to alignment is overruled by dataTable or injected styles.  **If** you really want dataTabled' rows as child rows, why not just add / remove those rows to the dataTable, below their "parent", instead of injecting a child table? It is really easy and would give you the desired layout right away.

Comment: That is what I was doing before, but the problem was the sorting done by Datatables.  My children rows were sorted too, and this isn't desired.  I try to make it works like this example : https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html   but you have to create the row by hand instead of using the json array received from ajax.

Comment: Then you must go the hard way, programmatically update the child columns to have the same width as their "parent" columns, and you must do a lot of CSS to prevent the inner dataTable to be styled the same way as the outer.

Comment: I did a demo here https://jsfiddle.net/survivant/811b41kL/2/   it works

Answer (score 1):

The best approach to your problem is using a combination of selectors (+ and >):

```
// For remove padding of nested table-cell
table.dataTable tbody tr.shown + tr > td {
    padding: 0;
}

// For set the width of first column
table.dataTable tbody tr.shown + tr table.dataTable tbody td.sorting_1,
td.details-control {
    width: 40px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alexndreazevedo/jpnr2e6c

Unfortunately, is only possible align nested columns setting a fixed percentual for each column. However it probably couldn't be readable with fluid text.

A workaround is change your markup. Depends of you!

Comment: thanks for the help.  I did some progress too.  here a more complete with javascript example : https://jsfiddle.net/survivant/qxfhh024/2/